# Recording Data from Behaviourspace

Tags: netlogo

I wish to store record the output of a `NetLogo` simulation run in two ways:

1. Output of some functions at the end of the simulation creating a single `.csv` for all simulation runs.(This is fairly easy to accomplish)
2. Output of some variables of an agentset at the end of each tick and store the values in a separate `.csv` for each simulation.

I don't know how to create a separate `.csv` for each simulation run and also accomplish the two at the same time.

In terms of the efficiency, while recording the data at each tick, does NetLogo write to `.csv` directly or stores in memory and writes once in the end?

**Note:** I run the simulations on `HPC` using behavior space.

**Tries:**

1. Using `RNetLogo` I can accomplish this, but it is too slow due to the inherent time in data transfer between `R` and `NetLogo`. Also, running NetLogo in parallel from `R` seems difficult to do
2. Tried writing an if condition in reporter tab in behavior space GUI, doesn't work. It seems allow only reporters.

EDIT:
[Link same question asked at d-level](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/netlogo-devel/RdZPcpXsIrI/7fR5coaADo4J)

Comment: @Seth Extremely sorry. You're right, I didn't realise it somehow. I was confused as to which place the question belonged to, that's why I asked it at both places. I should certainly have linked it.

Comment: re: the "if condition in reporter tab" part, you need to use `ifelse-value` instead of `if`

Comment: re: "does NetLogo write once at the end", this is documented in the BehaviorSpace section of the NetLogo User Manual. spreadsheet format writes everything at the end; table format writes as it goes.